# How can I turn off hardware acceleration for certain HTML elements via CSS?

Tags: iphone, html, css, jquery-mobile, hardware-acceleration

I created a very complex web app using HTML5, CSS3 and jQueryMobile.

It seems like jQueryMobile turns on hardware acceleration here and there via `translate3D` and/or `translateZ`.

Now I want to turn this off for certain HTML elements.

This gives me two questions:

- Is there a css property/attribute or something that I can use to tell the browser to turn off hardware acceleration for certain elements?
- If not: I will have to find the places where either `translate3D` or `translateZ` is used and simply remove them, right? How can I do that? The whole markup is very complex with many HTML elements. I can't go through each element in the inspector and search for it.

---

**Update:** *The reason why I want to fix this*

In my web app there are some elements which need to be swipeable (e.g. an image gallery). In this case I need hardware acceleration. Same for div containers that require iScroll and every other element which should be animated (e.g. slide- and fade-animations).

However, there are many parts of the app which are static (not animated). Using a special startup option in Safari, I was able to make the parts which get hardware-accelerated visible. This way I noticed that THE WHOLE app gets hardware-accelerated, not only the necessary parts.

IMHO this is not a good thing because:

- Accelerating the whole thing will cause heavy load to the GPU which makes the whole app stutter while scrolling.
- AFAIK it's best practice to let the CPU do the static stuff while the GPU only handles all the fancy animated stuff.
- When animations have ended, hardware acceleration should be deactived because it's not necessary anymore and would shorten battery lifetime.

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us what problem you're really trying to solve.  Why is hardware acceleration a bad thing?  Do you just need to fix your timing? As far as I know, it's the browser's business when it chooses to use hardware acceleration and when it doesn't and this can change from one browser version to another.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sure, I added that info to my original question. (Afaik, there are browsers which decide on their own when to trigger hardware acceleration and when not (e.g. IE) but there are also browsers that require hacks like `translateZ(0)` and `translate3D(0,0,0)` to activate hardware acceleration for certain elements.

Comment: I don't think any of the reasons you cite for not wanting acceleration are correct across all browsers/devices.  The browser decides to use the GPU over the CPU when the browser believes the GPU to be advantageous to performance and to battery life - not the other way around.  Plus, this changes from browser to browser and from release to release as the browsers are improved and as the hardware that they run on evolves.  I don't see how you could possibly know in your web page what acceleration was best or harmful in any given browser/device combination.

Comment: @jfriend00 I simply tested it out on various browsers and turning on/off hardware acceleration.

Comment: do you intend to retest every time a new browser version comes out?  Browsers will change their behavior in support of acceleration from time to time - that's my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through thousands of thousands of lines of CSS code, I found this:

```
.ui-page{-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden !important}
```

This was active for all pages and caused the problem. Removing that line fixed it for me.

Comment: I don't have this line in my app, so how am I supposed to turn off acceleration, please?